# Database integration for iOS and Android in Unity3d

Tags: android, ios, database, plugins, unity-game-engine

I am developing a game for iOS and Android, in which I need to implement a complex database. So I want to integrate SQLite database with Unity3d which would work on both iOS and Android. I have come across many SDKs which were providing the SQLite integration either for iOS or Android but not for both at same time. Is there any other free plugin or SDK which can implement database for both iOS and Android?

Should I use other database like MySQL , XML or JSON. Can these be integrated with both iOS and Android?

Comment: http://gamesforsoul.com/2012/03/sqlite-unity-and-ios-a-rocky-relationship/

Comment: Is it for android too ?

Comment: On Android the situation is as described for Windows. Pretty trivial. I'll do a large writeup when I have the time, but I don't at the moment. And I'll have to verify and test a couple of things on my iOS side. So just a comment for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [playerprefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) it will work on both iOS and android